# Updating TextViews when button is pressed in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I have two fragments that are supposed to update a third fragment which updates TextViews in two different `TableLayouts` wrapped in a `linearlayout`

Here's my third fragment:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    static TextView pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9, pos10, pos11, pos12, grocTot;
    static TextView oth1, oth2, oth3, oth4, oth5, oth6, oth7, oth8, oth9, oth10, oth11, oth12, othTot;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_layout, container, false);

        pos1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.grocstore1);
        ...

        oth1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.othstore1);
        ...

        return view;
    }

    //when button is pressed in first fragment, this updates
    public void updateTable() {
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dir/savings.csv");
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> savingList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 0, total = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] strings = line.split(",");
                for(String s : strings) {
                    savingList.add(s);
                    //total += Integer.parseInt(strings[count+3]);
                }
                //System.out.println(savingList.get(count));
                count += 4;
                total += Integer.parseInt(savingList.get(count - 2));
                //System.out.println(total);
                //System.out.println(count);
            }
            //System.out.println(count);
            if(count == 4) {
                pos1.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-4));
                pos2.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-3));
                pos3.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-2));
                pos4.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-1));
                pos5.setText("-");
                pos6.setText("-");
                pos7.setText("-");
                pos8.setText("-");
                pos9.setText("-");
                pos10.setText("-");
                pos11.setText("-");
                pos12.setText("-");
            }
            else if (count == 8){
                pos1.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-4));
                pos2.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-3));
                pos3.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-2));
                pos4.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-1));
                pos5.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-8));
                pos6.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-7));
                pos7.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-6));
                pos8.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-5));
                pos9.setText("-");
                pos10.setText("-");
                pos11.setText("-");
                pos12.setText("-");
            }   
            else {
                pos1.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-4));
                pos2.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-3));
                pos3.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-2));
                pos4.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-1));
                pos5.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-8));
                pos6.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-7));
                pos7.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-6));
                pos8.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-5));
                pos9.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-12));
                pos10.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-11));
                pos11.setText("$"+savingList.get(savingList.size()-10));
                pos12.setText(savingList.get(savingList.size()-9));
            }
            //grocTot.setText("$"+String.valueOf(total));
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //when button is pressed in second fragment, this updates
    public void updateTable2() {
        File myFile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dir/other.csv");
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> savingList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 0, total = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile2));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] strings = line.split(",");
                for(String s : strings) {
                    savingList2.add(s);
                    //total += Integer.parseInt(strings[count+3]);
                }
                //System.out.println(savingList.get(count));
                count += 4;
                total += Integer.parseInt(savingList2.get(count - 2));
                //System.out.println(total);
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            if(count == 4) {
                oth1.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-4));
                oth2.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-3));
                System.out.println("sup sfkj" + savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-4));
                oth3.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-2));
                oth4.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-1));
                oth5.setText("-");
                oth6.setText("-");
                oth7.setText("-");
                oth8.setText("-");
                oth9.setText("-");
                oth10.setText("-");
                oth11.setText("-");
                oth12.setText("-");
            }
            else if (count == 8){
                oth1.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-4));
                oth2.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-3));
                oth3.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-2));
                oth4.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-1));
                oth5.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-8));
                oth6.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-7));
                oth7.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-6));
                oth8.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-5));
                oth9.setText("-");
                oth10.setText("-");
                oth11.setText("-");
                oth12.setText("-");
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("sup sfkj" + savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-4));
                oth1.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-4));
                oth2.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-3));
                oth3.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-2));
                oth4.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-1));
                oth5.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-8));
                oth6.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-7));
                oth7.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-6));
                oth8.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-5));
                oth9.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-12));
                oth10.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-11));
                oth11.setText("$"+savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-10));
                oth12.setText(savingList2.get(savingList2.size()-9));
            }
            //othTot.setText("$"+String.valueOf(total));
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The first update method works and the table updates, but the second one doesn't show anything. I tested the file to see if it was working and it writing and reading to it work fine.

Here's the `linearlayout` with the tables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow  
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView9"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:typeface="serif"  
                android:textSize="18sp"  
                android:text="Grocery Savings"  
                android:gravity="center"  
                android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/store0"
                android:text="Store"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spent0"
                android:text="Spent"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saved0"
                android:text="Saved"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coupons0"
                android:text="Coupons"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocstore1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocspent1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocsaved1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groccoupons1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocstore2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocspent2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocsaved2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groccoupons2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocstore3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocspent3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grocsaved3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groccoupons3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" 
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow  
            android:id="@+id/tableRow05"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView09"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:typeface="serif"  
                android:textSize="18sp"  
                android:text="Other Savings"  
                android:gravity="center"  
                android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/store00"
                android:text="Store"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spent00"
                android:text="Spent"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saved00"
                android:text="Saved"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coupons00"
                android:text="Coupons"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow02"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othstore1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othspent1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othsaved1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othcoupons1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow03"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othstore2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othspent2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othsaved2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othcoupons2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow04"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othstore3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othspent3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othsaved3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/othcoupons3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>   

    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Grocery Savings:"
        />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/grocTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other Savings:"
        />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/othTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

I've checked the syntax two or three times and can't find anything wrong with it so I have no idea why this won't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

updateTable calls in MainActivity:

```
public void onButtonClick() {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment f = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(0));
        ((HistoryFragment) f).updateTable();
    }

    public void onButtonClick2() {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment f2 = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(0));
        ((HistoryFragment) f2).updateTable2();
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

I placed `System.out.println(oth1.getText().toString());` in the UpdateTable2() method to see if the string was getting placed in there and it was, so it seems to be just a problem with displaying the value in the `tablelayout`.  Still have no idea why though.

**EDIT 3**

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

        static EditText spent,saved,coupons;
        Button writeExcelButton;
        Spinner spinner;
        UpdateButton updateButton;

        public interface UpdateButton {
            public void onButtonClick();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
                try {
                    updateButton = (UpdateButton) activity;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                            + " must implement UpdateFile");
               }
         }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_layout, container, false);

            setSpinnerContent(view);

            spent = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_spent1);
            saved = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_saved1);
            coupons = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_coupons1);

            writeExcelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_addGroc);
            writeExcelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  UpdateFile();
                  buttonClicked(v);
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        private void setSpinnerContent (View view) {
            //set spinner
        }

        public void UpdateFile() {
            //write to file
        }

       public void buttonClicked(View v) {
            updateButton.onButtonClick();
        }
    }
```

Second fragment:

```
public class Add2Fragment extends Fragment {

    static EditText spent,saved,coupons;
    Button writeExcelButton;
    Spinner spinner;
    UpdateButton2 updateButton;

    public interface UpdateButton2 {
        public void onButtonClick2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                updateButton = (UpdateButton2) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement UpdateFile");
           }
     }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add2_layout, container, false);

        setSpinnerContent(view);

        spent = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_spent2);
        saved = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_saved2);
        coupons = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_coupons2);

        writeExcelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_addOth);
        writeExcelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              UpdateFile();
              buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void setSpinnerContent (View view) {
        //set spinner
    }

    public void UpdateFile() {
        //write to file
    }

   public void buttonClicked(View v) {
        updateButton.onButtonClick2();
    }
}
```

Comment: where your calling `updateTable()` and `updateTable2()` function?

Comment: In the main activity. I'll edit my post so it'll show them.

Comment: I don't see any Buttons in that XML. Where are your Buttons?  I also don't see any calls setting a click listener in the code.  Are you sure you set the listener?

Comment: Yep, I'll add my other fragments to my post.